# VHDL Loop Statement error: loop must terminate within 10,000 iterations

Tags: vhdl

```
architecture Behavioral of INST_CACHE is

begin

    init_cache : process (INIT)
        subtype word is std_logic_vector(0 to 31);
        type storage_array is array (natural range 0 to 2**32 - 1) of word;
        --type storage_array is array (0 to 2**32 - 1) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (DATA_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
        variable storage : storage_array;
        variable index : natural;

        type load_file_type is file of word;
        file load_file : load_file_type
            open read_mode is "C:\cachecontent.bin";

    begin

        -- load ROM contents from load_file
        index := 0;
        while not endfile(load_file) loop
            read(load_file, storage(index));
            index := index + 1;
        end loop;

        if rising_edge(CLK) then
            InstCacheOut1 <= storage(to_integer(unsigned(InstCacheIn1)))&InstCacheIn1&'1'; -- instrukcija & PC te instrukcije & valid bit
            InstCacheOut2 <= storage(to_integer(unsigned(InstCacheIn2)))&InstCacheIn2&'1'; -- instrukcija & PC te instrukcije & valid bit
        end if;

    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

I want to simulate a simple cache.
I will load instructions from a file into a structure.
However I get the error

> Error (10536): VHDL Loop Statement error at InstCache.vhd(49): loop
>   must terminate within 10,000 iterations

The line the error is reported at is:

```
    while not endfile(load_file) loop
```

I'm guessing the file isn't opened correctly or maybe it doesn't have the EOF character.
First, am I opening files in the right manner?
Second, what extensions are supported?
Third, do I have to manually add EOF character.
Fourth: can something else be a problem?

Comment: See [VHDL Loop Statement error at <location>: loop must terminate within 10,000 iterations](http://quartushelp.altera.com/13.1/mergedProjects/msgs/msgs/evrfx_vhdl_loop_does_not_term.htm). This is a tool implementation limitation likely based on stack limits. Note the suggestion you use multiple loop statements. Also note the chances of hitting `rising_edge(CLK)` may be infinitesimal to nonexistent. Also note a 2**32 memory is generally considered unreasonably large. It get's passed on the same expression stack.

Comment: The iterarions are limited, because you use a while loop, if you use a for loop, there won't be any restriction, because for loops are finite loops. There is no EOF character in files. You can open any file unless your VHDL can handle the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know for sure why you get that error message. I would agree with user1155120's comment, this is a tool limitation and not a VHDL's error.

However, they are many incoherent things in your design. So many that I feel you should put your time in revisiting your design instead of fixing it. A list of what I saw:

- storage describe a memory of 16GB, yet your entity is called `INST_CACHE`. Caches usually ranges from few kilobytes to few megabytes. Why 16GB then?
- It takes at least 4 bits to simulate a std_logic (since it has 9 possible states). Your design would eat up 64GB of your computer's memory, which is humongous.
- You defined `storage_array`'s range as `natural range 0 to 2**32 - 1`. The problem is, this is impossible in VHDl since `natural` is a subtype of `integer`, which can only take values from `-2**31 to 2**31-1`, hence a natural can't have a range up to `2**32-1`.
- As user1155120 pointed out, your code inside `rising_edge(clk)` will likely never execute. To execute, it would requires the signal `INIT` to change value on the same simulation delta cycle than `clk` rising. You will also re-trigger the initialization code every time `INIT` changes, whereas you probably want that code to execute only once.

Comment: See IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.2.3.2 Predefined integer types "...The only predefined integer type is the type INTEGER. The range of INTEGER is implementation dependent, but it is guaranteed to include the range –2147483647 to +2147483647. It is defined with an ascending range." (So that's a minimum range, -2\**31-1 to 2\**31-1). All this also shows the value of providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) allowing someone to poke through all the errors.